# how to make a solid title with text in the middle flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I have a list that contains tables with results

```
data_list <- list(structure(list(GROUP = "3\nN=0 (0%)", col6 = "NA", col7 = "NA", 
    dif = "col6-col7: NA", p.value = "col6-col7: NA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(GROUP = "3\nN=9 (100%)", 
    col1 = "5 [3; 7.5] \n 5.29 ± 2.81 \n ( 2 - 9 )", col2 = "8 [6.5; 10.5] \n 8.43 ± 2.64 \n ( 5 - 12 )", 
    dif = "col1-col2: -3 [-3; -3] \n -1.29   [-2.32; -0.26]", 
    p.value = "col1-col2: 0.015*"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(GROUP = "3\nN=9 (100%)", col8 = "NA", col6 = "NA", 
        dif = "col8-col6: NA", p.value = "col8-col6: NA"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Then I combine them into one data frame and get a common:

```
data_common <- structure(list(GROUP = c("3\nN=0 (0%)", "GROUP", "3\nN=9 (100%)", 
"GROUP", "3\nN=9 (100%)"), col6 = c("NA", "col1", "5 [3; 7.5] \n 5.29 ± 2.81 \n ( 2 - 9 )", 
"col8", "NA"), col7 = c("NA", "col2", "8 [6.5; 10.5] \n 8.43 ± 2.64 \n ( 5 - 12 )", 
"col6", "NA"), dif = c("col6-col7: NA", "dif", "col1-col2: -3 [-3; -3] \n -1.29   [-2.32; -0.26]", 
"dif", "col8-col6: NA"), p.value = c("col6-col7: NA", "p.value", 
"col1-col2: 0.015*", "p.value", "col8-col6: NA")), row.names = 2:6, class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to get a table that looks like this

[image]

where headers can be set

```
c("col1","col2","col3")
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Update

If you want to use `merge` for the quasi-header rows, first, you have to change the data a bit from my original answer.

Instead of adding the heading name to the center column, it needs to be added to the first column.

```
dc2 <- rbind(as.data.frame(col.names = names(data_common), # add first row
                           x = list("Col1", NA, NA, NA, NA)),
             data_common)
head(dc2)    # inspect what was expected
dc2[3, ] <- c("Col2", NA, NA, NA, NA) # replace other title rws
dc2[5, ] <- c("Col3", NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Now that you merge the cells, you no longer need the function `border_outer`. You will need to modify the `surround` function, though. It will now include all rows.

```
(ft <- flextable(dc2) %>% delete_part(part = "header") %>% # remove col headings
    merge_h_range(i = c(1, 3, 5), j1 = 1, j2 = 5, part = "body") %>% 
    surround(i = 1:6, j = c(1:5),                          # borders between cells
             border = fp_border_default(width = 1), part = "body") %>% 
    style(i = c(1, 3, 5),                                  # center title rows
          pr_p = fp_par(text.align = "center", padding = 3)) %>%
    style(i = c(2, 4, 6),             # adding padding/spacing to non-title rows
          pr_p = fp_par(line_spacing = 1.5, padding = 3)) %>% 
    width(width = .95, unit = "in")                        # column widths uniform
)
```

It doesn't look different from this perspective. However, if you used `autofit` instead of setting a specific width, it would look different.

[image]

Without `width`:

```
flextable(dc2) %>% delete_part(part = "header") %>% # remove col headings
  merge_h_range(i = c(1, 3, 5), j1 = 1, j2 = 5, part = "body") %>% 
  surround(i = 1:6, j = c(1:5),                          # borders between cells
           border = fp_border_default(width = 1), part = "body") %>% 
  style(i = c(1, 3, 5),                                  # center title rows
        pr_p = fp_par(text.align = "center", padding = 3)) %>%
  style(i = c(2, 4, 6),             # adding padding/spacing to non-title rows
        pr_p = fp_par(line_spacing = 1.5, padding = 3)) %>% 
  set_table_properties(width = 1, layout = "autofit")
```

[image]

##### Originally wrote

This renders the same as you have depicted. Even if it's not exactly what you want in the end, it should get you going in the right direction.

I modified the data. If you call something a "header" it goes to the top. However, you can put whatever you want in the body.

I removed your not 'headings' rows from `data_common` (rows 2 and 4). Then I added three rows, one for each of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`. I placed `NA` in cols 1, 2, 4, and 5.

There are now 6 rows in this data frame. I used that data to create the table. I start out by *deleting* the header row (where the column names would be placed). This actually removes the top border from the table, so I add an outer border around the body. Next, I added borders around all cells in rows 2, 4, and 6. Next, I centered the text in the rows with the `col` titles. I also added line spacing and padding to the non-title type rows. Then I made the column widths uniform so that these title-type rows were centered in the table.

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)

dc2 <- rbind(as.data.frame(col.names = names(data_common), # add first row
                           x = list(NA, NA, "Col1", NA, NA)),
             data_common)
head(dc2)    # inspect what was expected
dc2[3, ] <- c(NA, NA, "Col2", NA, NA) # replace other title rws
dc2[5, ] <- c(NA, NA, "Col3", NA, NA)

(ft <- flextable(dc2) %>% delete_part(part = "header") %>% # remove col headings
    border_outer(part = "body", 
                 border = fp_border(width = 1)) %>%        # re-add borders
    surround(i = c(2, 4, 6), j = c(1:5),                   # borders between cells
             border = fp_border_default(width = 1), part = "body") %>% 
    style(i = c(1, 3, 5),                                  # center title rows
          pr_p = fp_par(text.align = "center", padding = 3)) %>%
    style(i = c(2, 4, 6),             # adding padding/spacing to non-title rows
          pr_p = fp_par(line_spacing = 1.5, padding = 3)) %>% 
    width(width = .95, unit = "in"))                       # column widths uniform
```

[image]

Comment: your idea suits me. A question arose. Is it possible to somehow display all the borders of the table and not draw them manually for each row?

Comment: I figured it out. Can you tell me how to make `marge_at` for lines 1,3,5 in your code?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that information.